# Error trying to run migration for mariadb through docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using `docker-compose` to set up a `Mariadb` database in a container and run a migration to get it ready for use. The issue is I'm getting an error of the following when doing so:

```
Enter password: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

This makes me think the database isn't set up at this point in the `Dockerfile` but I could be wrong. Any ideas?

`Dockerfile` contents:

```
FROM mariadb:10.0.37
ADD db /db
WORKDIR /db
RUN mysql --user userExample --password passwordExample < migrate.sql
```

`docker-compose.yaml` contents:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build: .
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=userExample
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=passwordExample
    networks:
      example_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.1

networks:
  example_network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

Comment: You need to connect to db from host?

Comment: Oh the Dockerfile is run from the host? That would be it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Dockerfile in the wrong way, confusing images with containers.

The `RUN` command will fail because the container doesn't even exist at that point so there is nothing to connect to, thus you don't need to setup a Dockerfile at all.

If the `migrate.sql` only needs to be read once with a clean database then you can mount the file on `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migrate.sql`.  You can read about this directory on the [docker-mysql documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

If you need to import it from an already existing database then just run the import command from the host or another container.

I don't recommend creating a mysql image with an embedded database because any changes will be lost when the container is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to connect to Db from host, simplest thing ever you can do is to start this container in the `network=host` mode. Thus container wont get it's own networking but instead will use host's one.

First update your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build: .
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=userExample
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=passwordExample
    network_mode: "host"
```

Second launch it: `docker-compose up`

Third, connect from host using `localhost` as database host name.